# Accept a specific type of file Matlab

Tags: matlab, file

I have a GUI using a Browe Button to search a file :

```
function Browse(app, event)
     FileName,FilePath ]= uigetfile();
     ExPath = fullfile(FilePath, FileName);
     app.FileTextArea.Value = ExPath;  
end
```

And i save the file Path in a Text Area.
I have another button that start a matlab script with the file path as parameter and so i would like to accept only a certain type of file (.ctm which is my own type of file) if possible like this :

```
if file is .ctm
    do something
else 
    print('a .ctm file is needed')
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you can do:

1. Display only the files with a certain extension with `uigetfile()`

   ```
   [fileName, dataDir] = uigetfile('*.ctm', 'Select a *.ctm file', yourDefaultPth);
   ```
2. Verify that selected file has a `.ctm` extension

   ```
   [data.dir,data.fileName,data.ext] = fileparts(fullfile(dataDir, fileName)); % dataDir and fileName from pt. 1

   if strcmp(data.ext, '.ctm')
       % do something
   else 
       print('a .ctm file is needed')
   end
   ```

Keep in mind that neither of the two will verify that the content of the file is the one you're expecting and if someone will manually modify extension of the file, your program will most likely crash. It's good for a start but if you want to do a more reliable check, you should verify that the content of the file is correct, not its extension.

Comment: That's exactly what i want to do the problem is that my file research button is in a different callback function than my Launch button, so i don't know if i can use  " [data.dir,data.fileName,data.ext] " value in my other callback function ?

Comment: Yes, you can use it. You can read about sharing data among callbacks [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html).

Comment: It's ok i found how to avoid this problem and embellish my app :) thanks a lot !